# LaTeX editors with VIM like commands

Tags: vim, latex

I have recently grown fond of VIM for simple scripts now that I know how to use it a little bit. (thanks VIM adventures!!!)

Is there a LaTeX editor out there with vim-like commands? Having the toolbar of Winedt with the VIM commands to move around the text and replace/substitute things would be great.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=vim+bindings+for+latex&oq=vim+bindings+for+latex&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.1994&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 ??????

Comment: It would be silly if I suggest you Vim?

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier thats what I just did :)

Comment: VIM adventures, is that a site I haven't looted yet? Going to google.. EDIT: Ah, it's not a tips/docs base. It's more like... a crutch instead of doing your actual work in VIM! Still nice though :)

Comment: See [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/5764).

Answer (score 2):

There is [vim-latex](https://github.com/jcf/vim-latex) which adds LaTeX support to Vim, if that is what you are looking for.

I recommend installing it using [Vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/vundle).

Comment: And in the GUI Version of Vim, aka gvim, vim-latex also provides some toolbar functionality.